# Binary Search Tree- passing elements to string problem

Tags: c++, search, tree, binary, binary-search-tree

I have a problem with printing out my BST via to_string method. I've added some elements to my Tree:

```
bst->addTo(10);
bst->addTo(12);
bst->addTo(5);
bst->addTo(4);
bst->addTo(20);
bst->addTo(8);
bst->addTo(7);
bst->addTo(15);
bst->addTo(13);
```

and tried to display them in string, but its not really working. I mean it starts to work, but after reaching nullptr (I guess) it crashes. Method:

```
string to_string()
{
    stringstream ss;
    ss <<"ID: " << root->index << " Data: " << root->data << " Left child: " << root->left_child->data << " Right child: " << root->right_child->data << " \n";

    Node<T>* tmp = root;
    while (tmp != NULL)
    {     
        
        if (tmp->left_child != nullptr)
        {
            tmp = tmp->left_child;
            ss << "ID: " << tmp->index << " Data: " << tmp->data << " Left child: " << tmp->left_child->data << " Right child: " << tmp->right_child->data << " \n";                
        }
        break;
    }
    return ss.str();
    
}
```

Obviously, displaying root node works fine. Also, when I put a break inside of loop it also shows the result of second node (5) but then it crashes (again, I think thats something about that node with 4 value has no right child or something).
I tried so many things but I just can't figure it out. Can someone help?
Thanks.

Comment: You check if `tmp->left_child != nullptr`, but then inside the if-clause you basically try to print `tmp->left_child->left_child->data` without checks, because you immediately set `tmp = tmp->left_child` after the if. So that's probably where you're getting nullptr dereferences.

Comment: Why don't you simply traverse the tree using one of the many tree traversal methods, and simply print the node value?  If you haven't written a tree-traversal code, then now would be the good time to write that code -- then this issue becomes very simple.

Comment: I have in order and pre order methods, but I wanted to have one with displaying ID numbers, children etc.

Comment: But your code shows no traversal, only a loop.  It should look exactly like the code you have already written (but didn't show), except that the node is printed instead of whatever you're doing with it now.